# How do I rebase without committing first?

Tags: git

This is an infinite loop. I want to resolve conflicts and merge what they should do without committing. Who can tell me how to do it? Thank you

```
Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git fetch

Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git rebase
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.

Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git stash save 124
Saved working directory and index state On master: 124

Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to refs/remotes/origin/master.

Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git stash pop
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   t2.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (7360745b1a57d463ad704e08be582d1841de27cb)

Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git rebase
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `git add`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you describe in more details your situation and what you are trying to achieve? A good starting point would be to add the output of `git status` command to your post.

Comment: There are no conflicts, and you don't appear to have anything to rebase either.

Comment: Try committing the changes.

Answer (score 4):

You've done it. You did:

```
git rebase          # rejected because you have unstaged changes
git stash           # tucked the unstaged changes away
git rebase          # ← this worked
git stash pop       # ← this is the one that did what you wanted
git rebase          # rejected because your unstaged changes are back, on the new base
```

Simple fact is, `git stash pop` is the merge you're asking for. Stash save makes two commits, of your index and work tree, based on your current checkout.  Stash pop *merges those changes* to your new checkout.

Comment: No, I want to merge the remote file and the local uncommitted part into a new local. I can resolve the conflict, but it does not let me do so

Comment: If stash pop reported no conflict, there's no conflict. If you have conflict *markers* that don't show up in committed content they're the result of you resetting an inflight merge at some point.

Comment: But when I use diff, I can see that files with the same name conflict, but I can't merge them,If there is no conflict, I should be able to rebase directly to the local, even though there is uncommitted content locally

Comment: Administrator@PC201710191858 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/1/giteeTest/test2/test (master)
$ git diff
diff --git a/t2.txt b/t2.txt
index 0c0bad7..4a70387 100644
--- a/t2.txt
+++ b/t2.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-12313
\ No newline at end of file
+12312
\ No newline at end of file

Comment: That's a difference, not a conflict. Your rebase said it fastforwarded. There's no possibility of conflict in that scenario.

Comment: Note that you can automate this whole sequence with `git pull --rebase --autostash` if that's what you want.

Comment: @Useless make that an answer, add in a "you're already doing it, you can make it a oneliner with" leadin, I'll upvote it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any conflicts it seems. What you have are uncommitteted local changes.

Comment: The local change files will continue to be modified, so I don't want to submit them immediately. But I'm worried that there is a big gap between the local and remote files, so I want to merge them first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).